# Metaprogramming for finder method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, metaprogramming

Let's pretend I have some items in Stuff table. The names are:
RedBaloon, SmallBall, BigShoe, ShoeString

I want to use metaprogramming to create find_by_name methods for me.

The issue that I'm having is that I want to using the following as the names for the methods:
red_baloon, small_ball, big_shoe, shoestring

NB: "shoestring" is not a typo.

Here's some code that I started with for you to respond to:

```
class Stuff < ActiveRecord::Base

  NAMES = ['RedBaloon', 'SmallBall', 'BigShoe', 'ShoeString']
  validates_inclusion_of :name, :in => NAMES

  class << self
      NAMES.each do |n|
          define_method "#{n}" do
              find_by_kind(n)
          end
      end
  end

end
```

Comment: It looks like you understand the metaprogramming concepts and have a good start. Do you have a specific question about how to do something or are you getting an error?

Comment: Fetch the method name in another array. If you had stuck on downcase. You could have used the underscore method http://apidock.com/rails/String/underscore

Comment: that answers it! add it as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like @apneadiving said in their comment, you case use the special `String#underscore` method. Here is how I would clean up your code:

```
class Stuff < ActiveRecord::Base
  NAMES = ['RedBaloon', 'SmallBall', 'BigShoe', 'Shoestring']
  validates_inclusion_of :name, :in => NAMES

  class << self
    NAMES.each do |name|
      define_method name.underscore do
        find_by_kind name
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I don't know if there are any other problems because I could not find good documentation on `validates_inclusion_of`, but I think this fixes your problem.

Also, in the future, you don't need to interpolate a string into an identical string (`"#{string}` is `string`) and, because both strings and symbols are valid names in these methods, you don't need to perform a conversion. Even then, use `#to_string`.